# Scrapy Error: 'NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme'

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to scrap a site but while running the script, I'm getting following error

> 'NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for
>   that scheme'

If the rule is not wrong, why does it occur and what's your suggestion, please help me. Thanks a lot.

code is here:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule, BaseSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor 
class FellowSearch(CrawlSpider):
    name ='fellow'
    allowed_domains = ['emma.cam.ac.uk']
    start_urls = [' https://www.emma.cam.ac.uk/']

    rules =(Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'\?id=\d+$')),callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)

    def parse_obj(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Comment: I see a space before`https`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove space before https in your `start_urls` change to `start_urls =
 ['https://www.emma.cam.ac.uk/']`.

Comment: Could you please check my scrapy rules ? its scrapy only 31 url but there is more than 100

Comment: You should open a new question and specify what urls you want to extract and I'd glad to help you.